# Proposal to revise "Some questions are still off-topic" listed items to be expressions that result in off-topic questions

Tags: discussion, help-center, documentation-proposals

In the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the headline: "Some questions are still off-topic ..." is expressed as a scoped list of off-topic questions.

However, some of the listed items under this headline express a criteria that results in inverse logic, or when off-topic questions are on-topic.

For example,

> Questions asking for homework help **must include** ...

This does not make contextual sense; For, it is not a list of on-topic questions based on criteria. It is a list of off-topic questions that *might* be based on criteria.

---

#### Proposals

> 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") that **do not** include the desired behavior, a specific problem **nor** error **with** the shortest code necessary to reproduce it.

Second listed item is logically fine.

> 3. Questions asking for homework help that **do not** include a summary of the work done and a description of the difficulty in the attempt to solve the problem.

Fourth listed item is logically fine.

> 5. Questions about general computing hardware and software that **do not** directly involve tools used primarily for programming.
> 6. Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration that **do not** directly involve programming or programming tools.

Comment: The section has been since updated, and I feel this proposal is out of date. Closing

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an outdated proposal in meta that seems no longer relevant.